# VS2008 Solution Template

Tags: visual-studio

In the past I have created ItemTemplates for classes that I regularly use in VS2008. I want to create a template for a solution that will have two projects, a Web Site and a Class library.

I have not been able to find any clear instructions on how to do it. I am not sure if it can be done. Does anyone have any links to a possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [detailed instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185291.aspx) for creating custom project templates in VS2008.

-Edit-

There is no such thing as a "Solution Template."  There are Item Templates (for new files), and Project Templates.  However, I think what you may be looking to do is to create a specific type of Project Template called a [Multi-Project Template.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I have come across Project templates, but I want to create a Solution Template. Thanks for the link.

Comment: There's no such thing as a solution template.  See my edit for details and a link to multi-project templates (was under the link I pasted before...)

Comment: Thats what I thought about a solution template. Thanks for clarifying.